# Undetected dangerous default value for mutable inside immutable (tuple of lists)

Tags: python, pylint

Why the following code does not trigger `dangerous-default-value` for `items` when using `pylint`? Is this an *unintended feature* of `pylint` (i.e. a *bug*)?

```py
def func(item, items=([],)):
    items[0].append(item)
    return items
```

My understanding is that it should be all means do, since:

```py
print(func(1))
# ([1],)
print(func(2))
# ([1, 2],)
```

Is there a standard way of sanitize this, or do I have to do it by myself?

(**Note**: This is just **toy** code to illustrate the issue.)

Comment: I suspect (though could be wrong) that pylint doesn't attempt to detect mutability of defaults beyond a fairly small set of common cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `pylint` triggers `dangerous-default-value` only for non-nested `list`, `dict` and `set`, and this is a poorly [documented](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:w0102) behavior, since the behavior for `set` is omitted, while the following:

```
def func(item, items=set()):
    items[0].append(item)
    return items
```

will actually trigger the warning.

---

The [FlyingCircus](https://pypi.org/project/flyingcircus/) package offers a [`freeze()`](https://bitbucket.org/norok2/flyingcircus/src/91dfb89246ae8e0a89cc8cecc126411e2a69f8fb/flyingcircus/base.py#lines-1270) function for recursively sanitize (nested) combinations of `list`, `dict` and `set` containers.

Disclaimer: I am the main author of the package.